# Giving a static IP to a VM in Server 2008

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-server, ip-address

I have a dedicated server in Las Vegas. Yesterday I learn the awesome things about VMWare Server and I got that installed on it. Then I placed a CentOS 5.5 in one of the VM and its running as it should. I can login into the Server 2008 via Remote Desktop and then launch the CentOS from the IE. All of that works great.

Now I have 5 dedicated Ips out of which the server 2008 is using 4 and I have 1 spare IP that I want to give it to that VM. How can I do this?

The ultimate idea is to be able to login into that virtual machine via SSH and install a webserver on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the CentOS VM's configuration and set the Network Connection Type of its virtual ethernet adapter to "Bridged."  This will effectively expose the CentOS machine to the physical network as if it was plugged into the switch.  Once you make this change, edit the CentOS guest's network configuration to use the spare static IP and then restart the networking service (or just restart the VM for good measure).

There's one possible gotcha - in a managed hosting environment, it's entirely possible that the switch equipment is configured to only allow the MAC address of your Windows host server to pass traffic.  Since using bridged mode for the VM effectively adds a second MAC, be aware of this.  If all other network configuration seems correct on your end and it still isn't working, query the hosting company and see if they can configure their switch to allow the second MAC.

Comment: It worked. :) Thanks again for the help on IRC as well.